# using group concat with condition in mysql

Tags: mysql, group-concat

TABLE_1

| id_product unique | code |
| --- | --- |
| 1040 | D2 |
| 1780 | B2 |

TABLE_2

| id_order_line | id_order | id_product | id_attribute | linked_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16 | 1 | 113 | 1215 | 0 |
| 17 | 1 | 146 | 0 | 16 |
| 18 | 1 | 31 | 0 | 16 |

TABLE_3

| id_product | id_attribute | core_product | core_product_atrribute |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 113 | 0 | 164 | 0 |
| 113 | 1215 | 164 | 1 |
| 113 | 1216 | 164 | 2 |
| 113 | 1217 | 164 | 3 |
| 113 | 1218 | 164 | 4 |
| 146 | 0 | 178 | 0 |
| 31 | 0 | 1040 |  |

Required output

| id_order | id_product | code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1641 | D2B2 |

I have attrited the following code :

```
select s.id_order,
CASE WHEN linkedto = 0 then s.main_product end as main_product,
GROUP_CONCAT(s.lens_attribute_code)
from (select 
    CONCAT("ch", od.id_order) AS id_order,
    CONCAT(xcm.core_product, xcm.core_product_attribute) AS id_product,
    case when od.linkedto = 0 then CONCAT(xcm.core_product, xcm.core_product_attribute) else '-' end as main_product,
    od.linkedto,
    l.code
 FROM TABLE_2 od
 LEFT JOIN  TABLE_3 xcm ON od.product_id = xcm.ch_product AND od.product_attribute_id = xcm.ch_product_attribute
 LEFT JOIN TABLE_1 l ON CONCAT(xcm.core_product, xcm.core_product_attribute) = l.id_product_unique)s;
```

the result obtained from the above query is wrong and can be seen below:

wrong_result

| id_order | id_product | code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | D2B2 |

Comment: Explain the logic which must be used, in details.

Comment: I would Like to use the group_concat on the 'code' column from the table_1 which matches the (core_product+ core_product_atrribute ) from table 3. eg -> 178  + 0 = 1780. Which in the table _1 has the code B2.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to predict joining logic I have found the next:

```sql
SELECT t21.id_order, 
       CONCAT_WS('', t31.core_product, t31.core_product_atrribute) id_product,
       GROUP_CONCAT(t1.code SEPARATOR '') code
FROM TABLE_2 t21
JOIN TABLE_2 t22 ON t21.id_order_line = t22.linked_to
JOIN TABLE_3 t31 ON (t21.id_product, t21.id_attribute) = (t31.id_product, t31.id_attribute)
JOIN TABLE_3 t32 ON (t22.id_product, t22.id_attribute) = (t32.id_product, t32.id_attribute)
JOIN TABLE_1 t1 ON CONCAT_WS('', t32.core_product, t32.core_product_atrribute) = t1.id_product
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cd929226e2cc2c329685825dac1cec0f